# How to find out a css value from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, json

I have the following code that lets me change the color of an event in a calendar when clicked to red.

```
 eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
   $(this).css('border-color', 'red');
 }
```

What I want to do is allow the user to change the color by simply clicking so it will change from red to green to blue to yellow etc.

```
     eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
       if red then 
           $(this).css('border-color', 'green');
       else if green
           $(this).css('border-color', 'blue');
        etc
 }
```

So I want to 'find' out what the present color is and if red change to blue, if blue change to green etc.  I will only have about 5 colours.

Comment: If you use classes and delegated events the cycle builds itself.

Comment: [and because i'm feeling generous, here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/cT3c5/)

Comment: I'm having trouble detecting the current css class because the events color is not set up initially as in your example.  Im using http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/ and it sets each event color like so: backgroundColor: 'blue'.

Answer (score 1):

The getter is the same function call you're making to invoke the setter, albeit without the value:

```
$(this).css('border-color');
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/

Note that the value that gets returned from the getter may not be what you expect.  From the documentation:

> Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet. Different browsers may return CSS color values that are logically but not textually equal, e.g., #FFF, #ffffff, and rgb(255,255,255).

For this reason, I would suggest that you assign your colors to specific classes, and then test and swap classes as you see fit.

@zzzzBov posted a great example of this on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cT3c5/

Comment: Did you try that? http://jsfiddle.net/uHrH9/ FF returns nothing while chrome returns rbg

Comment: Great thanks, I notice that its returning the rgb value e.g for yellow its 0,0,255, can I get this converted to e.g. the word "yellow"??

Comment: Yes, I have tried it and I know what it does.  If you decide to go this route, you need to read the documentation on the function to understand how it works and work around the response values.  There is a simpler way (in my opinion), and I'll update the answer with a suggestion.

Comment: @HarryBoy you should go with the add class route although I would not bind 3 handlers for one element, just check if class red exist or not and change colour accordingly http://jsfiddle.net/cT3c5/1/

Answer (score 1):

You will need this:

```
$("#id").css("border-left-color")
```

This below will return an empty string,

```
$(this).css('border-color');
```

The border-color property actually sets the 4 properties border-top-color, border-right-color, border-bottom-color, and border-left-color, it is a combination of all these shorthand props. If you want to get the border-color, you need to specify which side. 
Say like this: border-left-color $("#id").css("border-left-color"). This should suffice as I am expecting every side does have the same colot.

Answer (score 0):

to get a css property of an element :

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElementId'),
style = window.getComputedStyle(element),
color = style.getPropertyValue('color');
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BNZDt/)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend delegating all styling work to CSS. Toggling classes on and off is a much better way of getting styles to change than setting inline styles via JS, because you can change how things work without impacting the JS code at all.

[Ideally you'd be able to delegate the event handler so that you can use different callbacks for different selectors](http://jsfiddle.net/cT3c5/).

If you're restricted to using the same callback, you can still toggle through classes, you'll just need to check state within the click callback:

```
eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var $this,
        add;
    if ($this.is('.a')) {
        add = 'b';
    } else if ($this.is('.b')) {
        add = 'c';
    } else {
        add = 'a';
    }
    $this.removeClass('a b c').addClass(add);
}
```